# Wlan0 interface disappears after overclocking sd card

Tags: pi-3, wifi, sd-card, raspbian-stretch, overclocking

When I add `dtoverlay=sdhost,overclock_50=80` to the `/boot/config.txt` and reboot my PI3 the wlan0 network interface disappears. When I roll back the change wlan0 comes back as well. I apply this change to a freshly installed Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) Lite installed using Noobs. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is WAD (working as designed) on a Pi3.
Always read the overlays README (/boot/overlays/README) when you're changing dtoverlays or dtparams.

Info for sdhost:

> N.B. This overlay is designed for situations where the mmc driver is
>   the default, so it disables the other (mmc) interface - this will kill
>   WiFi on a Pi3. If this isn't what you want, either use the sdtweak
>   overlay or the new sd_* dtparams of the base DTBs.